# Access report from two tables using selected rows from second table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to create Access report from two tables with already created relationship. My problem is that the second table has more than one row for each entry in the connected field name. I need the value only from the first row of the second table for each entry. Number 1 in the column titled criterion in the second table corresponds to the first row which I want to keep. Consider the following example:

```
First table
name value 
100  2
101  0
107  20

Second table
name test criterion
100  9    1
100  7    2
101  6    1
```

The two tables are connected using "name". I need to see the following in my report:

```
Report
name vale test
100  2    9
101  0    6
```

So, the second row of the second table is skipped since it has a duplicate name entry- i.e., 100. Can anyone please guide me how it can be done?

Comment: Why do you want the 'first' row - because it has maximum value? Need some kind of criteria for selecting records.

Comment: There is another column in the second table which has the selection criterion. I title this column "criterion". this column has numbers 1, 2 and 3. Number 1 always corresponds to the first row which is what i need to keep in the report. I update my post to show this.

Comment: Then use WHERE clause with that criteria - `WHERE criterion=1`. Will every name be in table2? If not do you still want every name from table1? Build a query that returns table2 records filtered by the criterion then join that query to table1.

Comment: yes, every name is in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `first_table` (
  `idfirst_table` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idfirst_table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `second_table` (
  `idsecond_table` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `criterion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsecond_table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Using the same data you provided as sample in your question, the query would be:

```
SELECT first_table.name, first_table.value, second_table.test
FROM first_table
JOIN second_table ON first_table.name = second_table.name
WHERE second_table.criterion = 1
```

And the result is:
[image]

This sample was tested on MySQL, but any database can be used for this, as it is pretty basic.  The CREATE TABLE statements might vary, but the query should be fine on other DB.